# Partial derivative of $g(x,y)=f(h(x,y),l(x,y))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f,h,l: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be derivable functions. If $g(x,y)=f(h(x,y),l(x,y))$,
is the following formula true? $$\frac{∂g}{∂x}(x,y)= \left(\frac{∂f}{∂x}(h(x,y),l(x,y)) +\frac{∂f}{∂y}(h(x,y),l(x,y))\right)\left( \frac{∂h}{∂x}(x,y)+\frac{∂l}{∂x}(x,y)\right) $$
It looks close to the chain rule $\frac{∂f}{∂x} \cdot \frac{∂x}{∂t}$

Also does this notation $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(h(x,y),l(x,y)) $ make sense as a derivative of $f(x,y)$ by the variable $x$ and after the derivation, substituting $h,l$ in the place of $x,y$ ?

Comment: The formula is not true in general. Correct would be the dot product $$\left.\left(\frac{∂f}{∂x}(h(x,y),l(x,y)) ,\frac{∂f}{∂y}(h(x,y),l(x,y))\right)\right |\left( \frac{∂h}{∂x}(x,y),\frac{∂l}{∂x}(x,y)\right).$$ (Sorry for the cryptic dot product, it was easier to type this way. I just had to copy and paste). This is just the [chain rule for higher dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions). The notation you ask about makes sense. Please do not use the title to replace the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Do you still require help with this?

Comment: @GitGud No but thank you for the answer, mine didn't seem to work and yours makes sense (and is easy to prove once i had the true hypothesis) ^_^.

Comment: Than I suggest you answer the question yourself below, so this question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(x,y)=f(h(x,y),l(x,y)) $ The actual answer, as suggested by @Git Gud is

$$\frac{∂g}{∂x}(x,y)= \left(\frac{∂f}{∂x}(h(x,y),l(x,y))\frac{∂h}{∂x}(x,y) +\frac{∂f}{∂y}(h(x,y),l(x,y))\frac{∂l}{∂x}(x,y)\right) $$

More info on the link below:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions